# Taking certification on Magento - Developer

Tags: magento2, magento-1, ceritification

I am thinking of taking Magento Developer certification. However, I am confused whether to go for it or wait till Magento 2 certification is released.

I am worrying whether if I take Magento 1 based certification, it won't have any market value if Magento 2 certification started. I am a bit confused. Any kind of advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

well everyone knows that magento1 end life is `nov 2018`,

But that does not mean after that magento1 sites stops. Magento1 sites would be there if they don't want to upgrade.

for that you can show that certificate to your client. and still magento2 certification is not there, so till that time you can show your understanding to magento by current certificates .

If you don't see certificate as magento1 or magento2 bases its generally shows you, your understanding towards magento.

So, My advice is,if you are planning to give magento certificate then do it.

**Update**

> Now onward there were no Magento 1 certificate exam would be there

Magento 2 developer certificate is here : https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer#.Wp44zObhVNB

you can even try to give magento 2 certification

Also there is another new exam for beginners : [Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer Exam](https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-associate-developer-exam)